# Can NodeJS run within a Rails 3 app? (to achieve high I/O concurrency)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, node.js, concurrency, websocket

I am quite intrigued by NodeJS at the moment and really like its ability to run high I/O concurrency.

I also read this interesting [article](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/08/03/why-rails-4-live-streaming-is-a-big-deal/#.UCfNSp3ibeA) related to the subject claiming that Rails 4 will be able to do high I/O concurrency and compete with Node at this task using "Live Streaming".

Now, my question is, can NodeJS run within a Rails 3 app?

I can't wait for Rails 4's Live Streaming!

Answer (score 0):

I found this video from RailsConf 2012 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iFBC-xbE9I titled "Evented Ruby vs Node.js" by Jerry Cheung.

He basically explains how to use Evented Ruby and that Evented Ruby is a solution but is hard, and complex. For now, it is easier to just switch to Node if our app is hugely evented. He also emphasizes it is very important to reduce latency before even considering concurrency.